# Flutter, how to create same path directory in Android and IOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
 File('/data/user/0/com.abc/cache/full.jpg')
        .writeAsBytesSync(class_image.encodeJpg(data));
```

I found out that Android works with this path. But in ios, I found out that it doesn't work with the error below.

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.abc/cache/full.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

I want to use the same folder for both. Is this possible? If not, the workaround is to manage the ios folder separately?

Comment: What's your point of using the same directory in both of them?

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Uhm .. the reason would be, because it is easy to manage in future? For Android or iOS, the default local path may change later by operating system update. However, if I could forcibly create a new path in Flutter (that is both are compatible), I thought that would be the best, so I asked.

Comment: building paths works for specific operatings systems, you need to programatically build the path you want for it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The storage directory of each platform is different
- You can obtain the local storage directory separately through the path_provider plugin, and then create your path.
- like this

```
  Future<Directory?> getLocalDirectory() async {
    return Platform.isAndroid
        ? await path.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        : await path.getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  }
```

Comment: What is the path.getExternalStorageDirectory()? wouldn`t it be path.getTemporaryDirectory()?

Comment: getTemporaryDirectory() There is a risk of being deleted at any time

Answer (score 1):

File('/data/user/0/com.abc/cache/full.jpg') I have observed that you have specified path manually. The path you speicified works only for android but for ios it is completely different.So instead of specifying manually use path provider and create platform specified path then use it

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
Future<Directory?> getLocalDirectory() async {
return Platform.isAndroid ? await path.getTemporaryDirectory(): await path.getApplicationSupportDirectory();  }
```

Comment: Why do you use getApplicationSupportDirectory() instead of getTemporaryDirectory() for IOS?

Comment: Both you can use they will definitley support.Temporary directory will clear after a certain period.But getApplicationSupportDirectory()  storage will not be cleared and they keep data hidden from user.so it will be very safe